# Deploying a plain bundle.js on a no-node-supported web server

Tags: deployment, jboss, webpack

I have a landing page (some.html) pointing to bundle.js . Under the chrome debugger I do see all my files getting loaded properly but still I get errors in the code like 'this' is undefined etc .

Please note :

1. I don't have node / npm / webpack installed
2. I am not running webpack-dev-server running on this server

What is the proper way to deploy / refer a bundle.js file ?
Do I need to install webpack globally on this server ?
I need to know is it possible to just get the functionality of my SPA through a bundle.js being pointed from index.html provided that bundle.js was generated using a webpack on my dev-machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like yes through an index.html we can point to a bundled js if all the functionality is client side and we can get the desired functionality. My reactApp was broken because it the underlying the page (old application) was supporting prototype.js and therefore react's internal functions had issues. Once I removed reference to prototype - my application is working in that old container –